# add extra row of total salaries

Tags: sql-server, unpivot

`salary` table:

```
EmpCode BASIC   HRA  CONV
--------------------------
   1    10000   500  300
   2    10000   500  300
```

Desired output:

```
   SalaryCode   SalaryDetails
    EmpCode           1
    BASIC           10000
    HRA               500
    CONV              300
   Total            10800

    EmpCode           2
    BASIC           10000
    HRA               500
    CONV              300
   Total            10800
 Grand Total        21600
```

"i like to show grand total after empcode '2'
 total"

i wrote the code for the total as

`select SalaryCode, SalaryDetails
  from

  (select ecode,BASIC,HRA,CONV,(BASIC+HRA+CONV)SUB_Total from empstb) a
  unpivot(SalaryDetails for SalaryCode in (ecode,BASIC,HRA,CONV,SUB_Total)) upvt`

`but i don't know how to add grand total to it`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of unpivot and GROUPING SETS. Not sure what you are using your final output for though

```
DECLARE @Salary TABLE
(
    EmpCode INT NOT NULL,
    BasicSalary INT NOT NULL,
    HRA INT NOT NULL,
    Conv INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @Salary (EmpCode,BasicSalary,HRA,Conv)
VALUES (1,10000,500,300),(2,10000,500,300);

SELECT  CASE
        WHEN GROUPING(CA1.ColName) = 1 AND GROUPING(S.EmpCode) = 1 THEN 'GrandTotal' 
        WHEN GROUPING(CA1.ColName) = 1 THEN 'Total' 
        ELSE CA1.ColName
    END AS SalaryCode,
    SUM(CA1.ColVal) -   CASE --Adjust the sum to exclude the EmpCode values
                            WHEN GROUPING(CA1.ColName) = 1 AND GROUPING(S.EmpCode) = 1 THEN SUM(S.EmpCode) / 4
                            WHEN GROUPING(CA1.ColName) = 1 THEN S.EmpCode
                            ELSE 0
                        END AS SalaryDetails
FROM    @Salary AS S
CROSS
APPLY   (VALUES (CAST('BasicSalary' AS VARCHAR(50)),BasicSalary,2),('HRA',HRA,3),('Conv',Conv,4),('EmpCode',EmpCode,1)) AS CA1(ColName,ColVal,RowPos)
GROUP   BY GROUPING SETS((),(EmpCode),(EmpCode,ColName,CA1.RowPos))
ORDER   BY ISNULL(S.EmpCode,MAX(S.EmpCode) OVER ()+1), ISNULL(CA1.RowPos,MAX(CA1.RowPos) OVER()+1) ASC;
```

Edit

Output has been tweaked as per OP. Do feel this level of presentation doesn't belong here, but this should be as required. As the EmpCode is included in the list some adjustments have to be made to ensure it isn't included in the totals. Also a position value has been added to output in the correct order

Comment: but i need to get 'EmpCode' in the 'SalaryCode','SalaryDetails' columns only not as as separate column in  the output

Comment: and also the 'HRA' row is not in order according to excepted output